# Last line of mail content in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, outlook-2007

can any one please let me know, Just am sending newsletter with few paragraph. and its getting received perfect. but the Last line of every paragraph of mail content has an extra line spacing in Outlook 2007? why?

see example below...

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
Ipsum has been the industry's standard

dummy text the 1500s...
```

but should be like below...

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
Ipsum has been the industry's standard
dummy text the 1500s...
```

Answer (score 4):

if your code has span-formatting, you can look for extra spaces after the end-tag. This space, will then be rendered with the e-mailclients default font-size.

eg:

```
<span style="font-size:10px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text the 1500s...</span> [space here]
```

The line with the last space will be tall enough to accomodate the space in default font-size (wich is often 12px). This will then look like the last line of your text is has a larger line-spacing than the rest.

Especially copy/pasting from other media, can cause this space to occur, but since you cannot see it, you can easily accidentially set your span tags so that space 'slips outside' of them.

/Klaus

Comment: I was having the same issue a simple 'apply source formatting' in dreamweaver fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a break tag immediately after the closing span tag.

EG: `<span>Some text</span><br>`

Comment: So adding more newlines will remove the extra ones that already exist...interesting... :(